# Logic and geometry problem

Tags: logical-deduction, board-games

My question is whether or not cycles can occur in the abstract game, Clearcut.

[image: Clearcut]

[Clearcut](https://www.marksteeregames.com/Clearcut_rules.pdf)

A few smart guys (and me) have been trying to either find a cycle or prove that one can't happen.  Ten days have passed without success.  Super hard problem.

Clearcut was designed by me. The only benefit I will derive from a proof is to be able to say with certainty that Clearcut is finite.

Comment: All relevant details should be presented directly, not in a linked pdf.

Comment: Ok.  I added a JPG of the rule sheet.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “cycle”?

Comment: You kill some of mine, I kill some of yours, you kill some of mine...  Endless cycle of turns. Game never finishes.

Comment: One of two things will clear up the matter.  Find an example of a cycle, thereby demonstrating that a cycle can happen, or somehow prove that cycles can't happen.   I'm sure the game is finite, but the proof is elusive.

Comment: In a true cycle, the board position must repeat exactly.  Same checkers on same squares and same player's turn.  But for this proof I think it would be suffucient to demonstrate that, even though the total number of checkers may decrease in one turn, on average the checker count must steadily increase.  Or, another way of looking at it: a decrease in checker count by one must always be preceded by an increase in checker count by more than one.

Comment: If it were possible to repeat a position, the checker count wouldn't have to grow on average.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the base game without any of the crosscut rules has been studied by mathematicians and iirc the first moving player can force a win, although the strategy is non-trivial. Can't recall the name or source though, I will add it if I remember.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "base game" for a square grid.  Hex and Y are the base connection games for hexagonal grids and have been solved for up to a certain size by computer, though this has no impact on human vs human play.

Comment: There is significant advantage to placing first in most connection games.  This is alleviated with the pie rule. That is, Player 1, say Black, makes what he considers to be an equitable first placement (like not too close to center), and then Player 2 decides if he wants to play as White or switch colors and play as Black.  This prevents Player 1 from claiming the center spot and having the double advantage of having an extra half stone on the board and controlling the center.

Comment: Probably the closest thing to a base connection game on a square grid is another of my designs, Crossway.  It's generally considered to be the simplest square grid connection game anyway.

https://www.marksteeregames.com/Crossway_rules.pdf

Crossway allows for diagonal connections though.  Clearcut is in a narrower class of connection games in which only horizontal and vertical adjacencies are relevant.

Comment: Maybe @quarague is thinking about [Bridg-It a.k.a. Gale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_switching_game#Gale).

Comment: Interesting design but not in the same class, using bridges instead of checkers. Flume is in the same family as Dots and Boxes but uses checkers instead of bridges.  https://www.marksteeregames.com/Flume_Go_rules.pdf

Comment: Would it be possible to transcribe the text somehow? That would make the post more readable for people with poor eyesight (zooming in is easier with text than an image, and screen-readers can't read the image), and make the puzzle more searchable.

Comment: The first sentence doesn't address the screen-reader or searchability concerns. I'm not sure even what purpose the second sentence has. The third sentence is an ad for your site. I will repeat the core question, since you didn't answer: could you please transcribe the text?

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question.  The PDF is more zoomable, searchable, and readable than the jpg image.  The purpose of the second sentence is that if you're interested in the rules of Clearcut, which I assume you are since this puzzle has already been solved, you might be interested to know that its rules have changed.  The third sentence is to give you a link to the rules of Clearcut in pdf, which should be much more accessible than the jpg here.  Also to provide you with links to my other games which you might also find interesting.

Comment: I couldn't care less about "advertising" here in this nearly expired thread.  Anything else?

Comment: I'm not interested in the rules per se; I'm interested in puzzles on this site being accessible long-term, and without forcing anyone to jump through hoops like using an off-site link. Would've commented to that effect when this Q was posted, but I was on strike. Thank you for explaining your intentions. On my end, I have no intention of even attempting to solve this puzzle.

Comment: I'd also be much more interested if the text could be transcribed. I can't explain why, but I find it much easier read and visually process than when it's in pdf or jpg. You can use free online OCR and correct any mistakes if you're short on time.

Comment: I don't understand why the off-site link is such a hurdle.  There are no ads or data collection, malware, or anything that I could imagine would be a problem.  I believe the PDF text is searchable, zoomable, and readable, obviating the need for a transcript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is a cycle.

> Blue and red both take two stones on turn 3.
> Each following cycle of 4 turns each they take 2 stones on turn 1 and 3.
> (each time with 3 vs 2 extended crossovers.)
>  [image]
>  Clarification: Starting with dark blue and red placed, some color starts, e.g. blue.
>  round 1: blue plays blue 1, red plays red 1
>  round 2: blue: blue 2, red: red 2
>  round 3: blue: blue 3 and takes red 1+2, red: red 3 and takes blue 1+2
>  round 4: blue: blue 4, red: red 4
>  round 5: blue: blue 1 and takes red 3+4, red: red 1, and takes the blue 3+4
>  round 6: the situation is identical to before round 2, repeat round 2....

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: (Note that it is 1 picture with 2 unconnected groups) If blue 2 is played, red 3 is not there (removed by blue the round before (blue 1), so there is no crosscut.

Comment: Your new picture makes it very clear. It is much simpler than I thought it would be.